# woocommerce product category tabs

Tags: categories, plugins, tabs

Can someone help me how to generate dynamic tabs with product categories in woocommerce. 
- product category as tab name, and their subcategories thumbnails as tab content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean 'tabs' as in the way WooCommerce presents the Product Description, Attributes, and Review on the product page then take a look at the template files for WooCommerce. You can find them at ../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates.

There's a good article on customizing the templates at http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/template-structure/

You need to follow these guidelines to make sure that your changes are upgrade safe.

Comment: No, I mean some independent tabs where can dynamically generate categories and subcategories like this [http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited](http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/)

Comment: Same basic code as what WooCommerce already uses. So looking at the code should help you out a lot.